# Bundling with webpack - scripts disabled error

Tags: javascript, webpack

Error message when bundling with webpack:

> PS C:\Users\Engr. Patrick\Downloads\webpack-playlist> webpack script-1.js./bundle.js
>   webpack : File C:\Users\Engr. Patrick\AppData\Roaming\npm\webpack.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this 
>   system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
>   At line:1 char:1

Comment: it says "running scripts is disabled on this system".  The link it gives explains what this means.  If you have permission to change your powershell settings this link will explain what to change https://winaero.com/blog/change-powershell-execution-policy-windows-10/

Answer (score 3):

You can set the ExecutionPolicy on the Powershell as an Administrator with the below command. Copy-paste this command on your powershell

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Please refer this for more details [Setting Execution Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-6)